# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n} |a_{2^{n}} | $

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ be a series of nonzero real number with $\sup\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \leq 1$.

(a) If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ absolutely converges, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n} a_{2^{n}}$ absolutely converges?

(b) If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n} a_{2^{n}}$ absolutely converges, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ absolutely converges?

Comment: Have you looked up "Cauchy Condensation Test"?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It works for positive nonincreasing series, but we cannot get that $|a_{n}|$ is nonincreasing.. we only have that $a_{n}$ is nonincreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $\sup_n\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1$ says that the sequence $(a_n)$ must approach zero if the sign of consecutive $a_n$'s is constant, but it does not say anything about the behavior of $(a_n)$ when the sign of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is differente, so we're going to use that.

(a)Let $a_{2^n}=2^{-n}$, and if $2^n<k<2^{n+1}$, let $a_k=-\dfrac{2^{-n}}{2^n-1}$. Then the sequence $(a_n)$ is given by
$$\left(1,\dfrac{1}{2},-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{4},\underbrace{-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\right),-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\right),-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\right)}_{3\text{ times}},\dfrac{1}{8},\underbrace{-\left(\dfrac{1}{7}\cdot\dfrac{1}{8}\right),\cdots,-\left(\dfrac{1}{7}\cdot\dfrac{1}{8}\right)}_{7\text{ times}},\ldots\right)$$
so $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely. Also, the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies the property required, but $\sum 2^na_{2^n}=\sum 1=\infty$

(b) Let $a_{2^n}=2^{-2n}$ and $a_k=-1$ for $k\neq 2^n$. Then $(a_n)$ satisfies the property required, $\sum 2^na_{2^{n}}$ converges absolutely but $\sum a_n$ does not converge.